# OTRS user password (command line)

Tags: otrs

What is the password of the *otrs* user when

you use the command "*su - otrs*", anyone knows

what's the password or the default password?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a question about programming but about using the OTRS application installed on your system. So maybe this question should be moved to SuperUser instead, the site for computer **user** related-questions, instead of here on StackOverflow.

Also, you don't describe how the OTRS user was installed on your system. Did you install OTRS via RPM? Did you install it from the debian package? Did you follow the 'generic' installation instructions?

The `otrs` user, when created using one of the above methods, does not *have* a password. This is the safest way creating a user!! The password can not be guessed or stolen. If you want, you can **set** the password, if you are the super-user. But most probably you must first make sure the user can log in, in the first place. Because by default the shell is set to `/bin/false` which means it is not able to log in.

```
# the user has no valid login shell
$ grep otrs /etc/passwd
otrs:x:114:33::/usr/share/otrs:/bin/false

# set login shell for user, as root
$ sudo chsh otrs
Changing the login shell for otrs
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Login Shell [/bin/false]: /bin/bash

# now you can set a password
$ sudo passwd otrs
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully

# ... which allows you to change to this user using the new password
$ su otrs
Password:

# you're now logged in as otrs!
$ id
uid=114(otrs) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
```

but please note that if you set the valid login shell, and you can use sudo, you can also log in "as" the OTRS user by using `sudo su - otrs` *without* setting OR using a password.